# $(-1)$-curves and base change along a field automorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, projective-schemes

Suppose that $E\subseteq S$ is a $(-1)$-curve inside a non-singular complex projective surface. By a *$(-1)$-curve* $E$, I mean that $E\cong\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$ and $E^2=-1$.

Now consider a field automorphism $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ and the fibered product along the morphism of schemes $\text{Spec }(\sigma):\text{Spec }\mathbb C\longrightarrow\text{Spec }\mathbb C$:
$$E^\sigma:=E\times_{\text{Spec }\mathbb C}\text{Spec }\mathbb C$$

> Is it true that ${(E^\sigma)}^2=-1$? In other words, is the
>   auto-intersection  preserved by the action of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ 
>   on $E$?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection product will be preserved for products $C\cdot D$, in the case where the intersection consists of reduced points. But these determine the intersection product in general (by the moving lemma).

So yes, it is true.

Comment: Why do you say that the intersection product will be preserved for $C. D$? I don't see it.

However many thanks for dedicating your time to my question.

Comment: Well, in that case the intersection consists of finitely-many reduced points. So after base changing by the field automorphism, it will still consist of (the same number of) reduced points.

Comment: Yes, intuitively this sounds very reasonable. However do you know any reference showing that intersection multiplicities are invariant for base change?

Comment: The base change of a reduced point by a field automorphism is again a reduced point. Intersection multiplicities aren't preserved by arbitrary base change, it's important that we're pulling back across a field automorphism.